# directory.GetFiles, how do i get it to spit out items as it finds them?

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io, listbox, filesystems

i'm using `Directory.GetFiles` to give me mp3 files, and i'd like to fill a `ListBox` with the results, but instead of stopping the program while it goes through the method, can i get it to search and fill the `ListBox` up as it gets the mp3 files?

so what i'm using is as follows (and it is failing to add them one at at time, it is adding them all at once when it is done)

```
private List<string> Getmp3sFromFolders(string folder)
    {
       List<string> fileArray = new List<string>();

       try
       {
           DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
           var files = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.mp3");
           foreach (var file in files)
           {

               fileArray.Add(file.FullName);
               Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(_AddMP3ToListbox, file.Name);
           }

           var directories = dir.EnumerateDirectories();
           foreach (var subdir in directories)
           {
               fileArray.AddRange(Getmp3sFromFolders(subdir.FullName));

           }

          // lblFolderSearching.Content = folder.ToString();
       }
       catch
       {

       }
       return fileArray;
    }
```

i did add `_AddMP3ToListbox = AddMP3ToListbox`

it does indeed add the mp3's to the listbox, but it does so all at once, not as soon as it finds it.  how can i fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx) instead of `Directory.GetFiles`.
`EnumerateFiles` will return the files as they're found by the system - not wait for all of them to be found.

Do this on a background thread and use `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to the UI thread as each one is found to add it to the `ListBox`.

Here's a quick example I threw together. Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="_FileList" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Go!" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here's the code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Action<string> _AddToListBox;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _AddToListBox = AddToListBox;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Action action = Go;
            action.BeginInvoke(null, null);
        }

        private void Go()
        {
            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\windows\system32\"))
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(_AddToListBox, file);
            }
        }

        private void AddToListBox(string toAdd)
        {
            _FileList.Items.Add(toAdd);
        }
    }
}
```

by no means do I intend for this to be a best-practices or all-encompassing example. Just showing you one way to do it. By the way, I picked the system32 directory just because it has a lot of files in it so I could test it. Still works almost instantly on my machine though.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know they had added EnumerateFiles.

Comment: Yep. I didn't know until recently either. It's in Silverlight too. Definitely useful for making things asynch.

Comment: can you give me a sample code in c# that outputs to a listbox?  i tried it and i'm getting slower times than with GetFiles

Comment: @darthwillard - what do you mean slower? Overall time? Or time to the first item appearing in the ListBox? It'll almost certainly be slower in overall time as you're adding things as they show up rather than all at once at the end. But it keeps the UI responsive and adds them as they go.

Comment: @darthwillard - I've added an example now.

Comment: why do i need `Action action = Go` and `action.BeginInvoke(null, null)`  what do they add to make it work?

Comment: sorry, but i can't get this to work for me, i have a listbox that uses a variable `folderName`, but when i try `foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderName)`, i get the error that i don't have permission to access the folders.  (it's a windows 7 error).   is there a way around this?  or is there an easier way to place action.begininvoke somewhere?